# How to improve the accuracy of region detection based on GPS

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin, gps

Imagine you have a map with multiple GPS regions next to each other, and a function that executes every 5 seconds with new GPS coordinates when `it` comes in:

```
GPSModel.observe { it =>
  // it.latitude, it.longtitude
  currentRegion = getRegionByCoordinates(it)
  if (lastRegion != currentRegion){
     doSomeThing() // region changes
  }

  lastRegion = currentRegion
}
```

The problem is that, due to the fact that GPS may not always be accurate, I don't want to fire `doSomeThing()` when `it` comes in automatically. Instead I want to confirm that the incoming GPS coordinates remain in the **same new region** for at least 20 seconds, and only then would the `doSomeThing()` function execute.

How is this possible?

Comment: How about going for a loop and sample a few times for 20 secs and check if it stays like that? is it not a option?

Comment: it might also be worth checking the sensor's reported accuracy to make sure you're some number of standard deviations (e.g. 4) away from the nearest border.

Comment: We would need to know how you are defining regions. Is it by some specific amount of minutes? Is it long/lat at all? Pixel count of a fixed-size map?

Comment: @TylerH It is described by long/lat polygons  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/polygon-tutorial